# Where is the RunServicesOnce registry key

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I have an application that updates software on the local machine.  I need the software to be updated prior to user log on, and have read that running the application via the `RunServicesOnce` registry key is probably the most appropriate to use for this purpose.

But I can't find this key using `regedit` and it doesn't appear in the same location as the HKLM RunOnce key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce`.

1. Where is this key located? Same in Windows XP \ Vista \ 7 \ 8 \ 8.1 \ 10 ?
2. How do I use it, are there any optional parameters?
3. How do I determine the user that the application is run as?  Is it run by the user that created the key?  If a `LocalSystem` service creates the key, will it be run as `LocalSystem` ?

Comment: [Same location in every version of Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for your help - where in that document does it specify the location of the RunServicesOnce key?

Comment: Wrong...Support article....should have linked to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/179365)

Comment: [More talk](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-to-start-program-before-user-logon-windows-7/2bff97c4-c037-437c-9fa7-b143a3ae5189?auth=1)

Comment: @Ramhound thank you... I checked RegEdit and this key doesn't appear to be present.  I created it manually and added a string value to run an app, which works under the RunOnce key however under the RunServiceOnce key it doesn't execute, and the key value is not removed.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Ramhound your second link clearly states that it applies to "Windows 95, Windows 98, and Windows Millennium Edition"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Where is the RunServicesOnce registry key**
>
> I have an application that updates software on the local machine. I
> need the software to be updated prior to user log on

### [**Start Program before User Logon Windows 7**](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-to-start-program-before-user-logon-windows-7/2bff97c4-c037-437c-9fa7-b143a3ae5189?auth=1)

> If you want it to start before the user logs on, you will have to
> start it as a service.   Here is the startup sequence of the major
> registry keys, starting immediately after bootmgr has been read and
> ending with the program shortcut entries in the two Startup folders.
>
> 1. HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\BootExecute. This can include instructions to schedule the running of chkdsk but
>    not user programs.
> 2. Services start next, followed by the RunServicesOnce and RunServices registry keys (if present)
> 3. User then logs on to the system
> 4. HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\UserInit. This points to the program
>    C:\WINDOWS\system32\userinit.exe and the entry ends with a comma.
>    Other programs can be started from this key by appending them and
>    separating them with a comma.
> 5. HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell. This should contain just one entry, explorer.exe.
> 6. Program entries in these 2 registry keys for ALL USERS start next: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run and \RunOnce
> 7. Program entries in these 2 registry keys for CURRENT USER start next: HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run and \RunOnce
> 8. Programs in the Startup Folders of All Users and Current User are started last of all.
>
> Important programs like antivirus and firewall
> start early in the sequence as Services. The icons that appear in the
> Notification Area (bottom right of the screen) are just their user
> interfaces, i.e. options and preferences.
>
> The additional location
> for 32-bit software in a 64-bit computer is HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node
> and HKCU.

### [**The Run Keys and Search-Order**](http://blog.cylance.com/windows-registry-persistence-part-2-the-run-keys-and-search-order)

> The registry is accessed even before the NT kernel is loaded, so it is
> very important to understand what the computer is configured to load
> at startup. The following list of registry keys are accessed during
> system start in order of their use by the different windows
> components:
>
> 1. HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session
>    Manager\BootExecute
> 2. HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services  (start value of 0 indicates
>    kernel drivers, which load before kernel initiation)
> 3. HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services (start value of 2, auto-start
>    and 3, manual start via SCM)
> 4. HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce
> 5. HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce
> 6. HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices
> 7. HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices
> 8. HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Notify
> 9. HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Userinit
> 10. HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell
> 11. HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell
> 12. HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ShellServiceObjectDelayLoad
> 13. HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
> 14. HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx
> 15. HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
> 16. HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
> 17. HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
> 18. HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\Run
> 19. HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\Run
> 20. HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\load
> 21. HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows
> 22. HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\SharedTaskScheduler
>     (XP, NT, W2k only)
> 23. HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows
>     NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\AppInit_DLLs
>
> **Note:** Some of these keys are also reflected under
> HKLM\Software\wow6432node on systems running on a 64bit architecture
> and with a 64bit version of Windows. I won’t be covering each of these
> in this post.

*Run your service as the LocalSystem account unless the account needs to access network resources at which point you'd create a domain service account, give it access to the applicable resources, and then hard-code its credentials for the service to run as. On the local machine, it'll have administrative permissions to everything and not require any password for the service credential.*

### [**LocalSystem Account**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190(v=vs.85).aspx)

> The **LocalSystem** account is a predefined local account used by the
> **service control manager**. This account is not recognized by the
> security subsystem, so you cannot specify its name in a call to the
> **LookupAccountName** function. It has extensive privileges on the local
> computer, and acts as the computer on the network. Its token includes
> the **NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM** and **BUILTIN\Administrators** SIDs; these
> accounts have access to most system objects. The name of the account
> in all locales is **.\LocalSystem**. The name, **LocalSystem** or
> **ComputerName\LocalSystem** can also be used. ***This account does not have
> a password***. If you specify the LocalSystem account in a call to the
> **CreateService** or **ChangeServiceConfig** function, any password
> information you provide is ignored.

Comment: "_If you want it to start before the user logs on, you will have to start it as a service._" How about `schtasks` instead?

Comment: You can technically run anything as a **startup** script or process "*at system startup*" to have it run as `SYSTEM` at startup before any Windows user account login, and without being a service at all for that matter. For example you can schedule a process to run at startup with Task Scheduler and that will work for that purpose too of running before the user account logs into the OS. Regarding "RunServicesOnce registry key" this answer was off the basis of that question—odd right! Good point though otherwise to accomplish what the OP asked but in a different way.